# Como puedo agrupar por lista de objetos en LinQ como una sublista

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> Este es el ejemplo de la lista que tengo |
> new Alumno("Nombre",edad',Nota),

[image: Esta es la lista que tengo]

> Este es el recorrido en Linq para recorrer toda la lista y traer los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Estaba intentando con este codigo tambien pensaba en hacer con un foreach pero aun no se como lo hago

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi pregunta es como agrupar los alumnos por notas mostrar cuantos de cada grupo y en un sub menu mostrasla

> lista de ellos agrupadas los alumnos por Edad cuantos de cada grupo y en un sub menu mostras la lista de ellos

> Pueden ser de grupos de 4 o de 3 alumnos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir como texto.. es mucho mas facil de copiar para todos, inclusive para quien quiere responderte.. usa el boton [edit] y pone el codigo como texto

Comment: Y cuando decis que queres agrupar, por que campo queres agrupar? como queres que quede la lista?

Comment: Agrupar por la longitud del nombre y mostrar aquellos grupos cuya suma de edades
es mayor de 60

Comment: Lee los enlaces que te pase... toda la informacion va en la pregunta... inclusive eso que queres hacer y no pusiste en la pregunta

Comment: a que llamas "cuantos de cada grupo" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ver si algo como esto es util

```
var query = from a in listaAlumnos
            group a by a.Nota into g
            order by g.Key descending
            select new {
               Nota = g.Key,
               Alumnos = g.Take(4)
            };

foreach(var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nota {0}", item.Nota);

    foreach(var alumno in item.Alumnos)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Alumnos: {0}", item.Nombre);
    }
}
```

Agrupas por las notas la cual usas para armar el `select` y con el `Take()` solo 4 alumos que esten en cada grupo de notas

Comment: gracias si Funciono